PQR + QR = 1012 alphametic
Beginner puzzle (suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving).
To allow new users to solve this puzzle and earn reputation points, I encourage all users whose reputation is 200 or more to not post an answer until 48 hours after this question is posted. Thank you!

In the addition shown, each of P, Q and R is a digit.


 PQR
+ QR
----
1012


What is the value of PQR?

Attribution:  Gauss Contest Grade 8, 2020

I have less than 200 rep but I would not consider myself a beginner puzzle solver. Am I allowed to post or not?

@Mike Sure.  Go ahead and post.  Thanks for being courteous by asking.

In this era of complicated puzzles and riddles, that take hours to solve, it is refreshing to see that you come up with simple puzzles like these for the beginners. Please dont let the downvoters discourage you.

@DrD Thanks for your encouragement.  I know that some people enjoy some of my simpler puzzles.  Not everyone has years and years of puzzling experience.  Sometimes I do get discouraged by the negativity of some of the things I have experienced and seen on the Stack Exchange sites.

I like the question, thanks for posting it

A bit late but my method is slightly different.

 working from right to left. R must be 2 or 6 because mod(2*R,10)=2 since 2Q must be even, and the 1 at the bottom is odd. R must be 6 two carry the one. Then Q is either 5 or 0 but to make ten you need to carry so Q is 5. P must be 9. (to make the 10 at the bottom).

So

 R=6, Q=5, P=9.



 For P I want it to be 9 so that a carry will make the 10.
 For Q I want 5 so that a 1 is carried over and we can get a 1 from another carry.
 For R we need a carry so 6 should give us that and the 2.

 So:

956+56=1012


I've edited this to place it behind 'spoiler' tags so that other people can try to solve it without seeing your solution first.


PQR + QR = 1012. We can infer from this, QR has to stay the same. We can also infer that QR + QR will have to go over 100. So, we do 112(the number that we would receive if P is taken out) divided by 2, which gives 56.


Then, we do 1012 - 56 - 56 which is equal to 900. We then do 900 + 56 to give us 956 for PQR and then 56 for QR.


Therefore, P = 9, Q = 5, R = 6.

